# Magento free shipping calculated on grand total

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Using standard magento shipping table rates or webshopapps matrix rates, i found that the free shipping is calculated on subtotal without tax instead of gran total (subtotal + tax). For sure, i would like to set free shipping in function of gran total.
I found that it is possibile hacking core code:

app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php

Changed line 60:

`|| ($request->getPackageValueWithDiscount() >= $this->getConfigData(’free_shipping_subtotal’))`

to

`|| ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >= $this->getConfigData(’free_shipping_subtotal’))`

Is this really the only way? Naturally, if so, i would create a "copy" of this class to override this method, saving it from future core changes.

Comment: Correct me, but GrandTotal is Subtotal + Shipping? This doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Gran Total = subtotal + tax; I was not so clear, you're right.
Anyway i've update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've set free shipping in Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules, and there it works for me.

Comment: This works great, fo me, too. It is even possible to limit the rule to specific countries! Thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 0):

Changed line 60: FROM instead of TO in the previous post

```
|| ($request->getPackageValueWithDiscount() >= $this->getConfigData(’free_shipping_subtotal’))
```

(FROM)

```
|| ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >= $this->getConfigData(’free_shipping_subtotal’))
```

Is this really the only way? Naturally, if so, i would create a "copy" of this class to override this method, saving it from future core changes.